# Bijectivity $f(s)$ such that $s\subset f(s)$, $f(s)$ outputs cardinality of $s$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set of objects, $|A|=n$ and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a fumetion which domain is the power set of $A$ ( Powerset $(A)-$ all subsets of $A$ ) and its codomain the set of natural mumbers $\left\{m \in \mathbb{N}\left(0 \leq m \leq 2^{n}\right\}\right.$. whereby :
for $$\text{$s \subseteq A$, $f(s)$ is the cardinality of set $s$}$$

I was wondering if in general $f$ is bijective or not. I think its not injective but I can't think of a counter example. As for the surjectivity I think its surjective but I don't know what argument to use. Any help is much welcomed.

I tried to search for counter-examples: For injectivity I think I need to find $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ such that $f(s_{1})=f(s_{2})$ but $s_{1}\neq s_{2}$ so if I just say $s=\{1,2\}$ and $s=\{3,4\}$ would this solve the case for injectivity?

Comment: Not injective: correct. For $A = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$ and $s_1 = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $s_2 = \{ 3,4 \}$ we have that $|s_1|=|s_2|$

Comment: @Kamola The problem is very poorly phrased. You are considering a given set $A$ (which need not necessarily be assumed finite) and considering the map $\varphi \colon \mathscr{P}(A) \to [0, \mathbf{a}]$ given by $\varphi(X)=|X|$, where $\mathbf{a}=|A|$ and you are asking whether in general $\varphi$ is bijective or not. The answer is no, not in general, but only in the particular cases $\mathbf{a} \leqslant 1$. As soon as $\mathbf{a} \geqslant 2$ you have at least two singleton subsets of $A$ which render the injectivity of $\varphi$ faulty.

Comment: e: yes. For every $m \le n$ if $A$ has $n$ elements, we have a subset of $A$ with $m$ elements.

Comment: By the way, the codomain is just $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and the cardinality of the power set of $A$ is $2^n$. So you cannot have a bijection.

Comment: @Kamola *(continuation of the above)* Nevertheless, bearing in mind the way $\varphi$ has been introduced above it will always be surjective.

Comment: Ah I see your point @ΑΘΩ what I meant in short is whether a set $s\subset A$ such that $f(s)$ outputs the cardinality of $s$ is bijective or not I think I can see why its not injective, and why its surjective

Comment: @Kamola Glad to know that the comment helped. In brief, as long as you are considering sets of cardinality at least $2$ they will have distinct subsets of identical cardinality (the simplest illustration being the singletons, but the other proper nonempty subsets equally find themselves in this situation) and as for the surjectivity of your cardinal evaluation map it will depend on what the codomain is. What is certain is that the image of this map will always be $[0, |A|]$.